# etc.bundle => warning: already initialized constant

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, macos-catalina

When I run Ruby scripts, I get 157 lines of warning messages like this:

```
/Users/clay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin19/etc.bundle: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_AIO_LISTIO_MAX
/Users/clay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin19/etc.bundle: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_AIO_MAX
/Users/clay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin19/etc.bundle: warning: already initialized constant Etc::SC_AIO_PRIO_DELTA_MAX
... lots more
```

After some digging, it seems like the Ruby/gem/bundle industrial complex is using both the RVM version of Ruby 2.6.3 **and** the macOS system version of 2.6.3 in order to resolve the `etc` gem.

My hard-won quick-fix is to uninstall the rvm-ruby's `etc` gem, like:

```
rvm use 2.6.3
gem uninstall etc
```

However, anytime I initiate a `gem update` on this version of Ruby, `etc` will get reinstalled, and I'm back to a torrent o' warnings. I cannot get the system-ruby to uninstall `etc` at all.

Is there a more permanent fix?

---

Deets:

```
rvm 1.29.9
macOS Catalina 10.15.2
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears I can suppress installing the `etc` gem in my `Gemfile`, like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.6.3'

gem 'cocoapods', '1.9.1'
# ... other gems
gem 'etc', :require => false
```

Because the system `etc` gem is already, um, "on the path", it all seems to work for now, but *yikes*, **do not like**.